# How to count from spring boot CrudRepository using curl?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, count, crud, spring-data-rest

I have a simple definition of a repo:

```
public interface StorageService extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {}
```

I can use curl to create and see elements. Examples of get and create (respectively) below:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/cars
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"licensePlate" : "Vegan is Moral" }' http://localhost:8080/cars
```

Basically, I'm using the `save()` and `findAll()` methods from [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.13.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html).

How can I invoke the `count()` method using curl, which is also defined in `CrudRepository` (without defining additional services)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible out of the box.
In my opinion(may be I am wrong.), this is because spring data rest is basically providing rest endpoints over HTTP methods(GET, POST, ....) for doing operations on your resource(entities) and get count is not an HTTP operation

But you can achieve this by couple of other ways.

1. Write a method like this in your Repository class.

   `Car countByModel(String model);`

This would make a GET endpoint available at */cars/search/countByModel*

or like this

2. ```
   @Query("select count(*) from Car")
   long getCount();
   ```

   This would make a GET endpoint available at */cars/search/getCount*

Comment: The `@Query` worked. Is it the same way that Spring extracts the data on all data sources?

Comment: countByModel should also work, provided you have a field named `model` in your entity class.  Not sure if i understood your second part of the question

Comment: I'm interested in counting all. Not by a filter. Thanks.